# UISearchBar: FilterContentForSearchText not working on a UITableView (results not shown on table)

Tags: uitableview, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

**PROBLEM PARTLY SOLVED, SEE END OF POST:**

Showing search results on a `UITableView` not working. The `table` stays blank, doesn't show any `results` but the `searching` must work because when I `search` for something not in the `table` I get immediately `"No Results"` text shown on the `table`.

Note: In `IB` I did `connect` the `delegate` of `UISearchBar` in `Connection Inspector` with my `Controller`.

Hope you can help.

**m:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) ? [self.seriesArrayFiltered count] : [self.seriesArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SeriesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Serie *aSerie = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"search is displaying");
        aSerie = self.seriesArrayFiltered[[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"search is NOT displaying");
        aSerie = self.seriesArray[[indexPath row]];
    }

    UILabel *valueLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    valueLbl.text = aSerie.name;

    return cell;
}


-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

    [self.seriesArrayFiltered removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    self.seriesArrayFiltered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.seriesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    return YES;
}
```

**h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SeriesTableVC : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *seriesArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *seriesArrayFiltered;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *seriesSearchBar;

@end
```

**When I change the following code I see the search results now but I like to know
why the label is not recognized.**

*In: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`*

```
//UILabel *valueLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
//valueLbl.text = aSerie.name;

cell.textLabel.text = aSerie.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells that you create do not contain a label, therefore

```
UILabel *valueLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
```

returns `nil`,  and setting `valueLbl.text = aSerie.name;` has no effect.

You have to create the label and add it as subview to the cell when you create the cell:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *valueLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:valueLbl];
}
```