# Custom UITableViewCell views are blank after searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I believe this question is my exact problem, but I was not able to fix the issue looking at the accepted answer. 
[UISearchBar: FilterContentForSearchText not working on a UITableView (results not shown on table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113714/uisearchbar-filtercontentforsearchtext-not-working-on-a-uitableview-results-no)

I have a `UITableViewController` that allows searching. It was working perfectly via the default `UITableViewCellStyle`, then I decided to implement my own custom layout for the cells. I did not subclass `UITableViewCell`, but instead added two `UILabel`s to the cell via Interface Builder and set up Auto Layout. I assigned them unique tags so that I can reference those labels in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It works great - everything appears as expected, until you search. The search does work and it displays the sections and rows, but the labels on the rows have no text so the cell appears completely blank.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"List View Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *leftLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *rightLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        leftLabel.text = ...;
        rightLabel.text = ...;
    }
    else {
        leftLabel.text = ...;
        rightLabel.text = ...;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I do know why the labels are blank. When you search, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil` so it inits a new cell with the reuse identifier, but that cell does not have a `viewWithTag:` and this results in left and right label becoming `nil`. So it obviously cannot add text to `nil`.

The answer provided in the link stated you should create the label in the `if (!cell)` statement and then call `[cell.contentView addSubview:left{right}Label];`. I did that, and then moved my label configuration code into that if statement as well. But when I do that, the main table's rows only has the default values of my left and right labels from Storyboard - it doesn't set the text of the labels. This is because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` doesn't return `nil` and instead creates a new cell, so it doesn't ever set the text because that's in the `if (!cell)` statement.

I could not figure out how to take care of both situations: when cell is nil and when it is not. What do I need to do to fix this?

More comments: I've never used xib files before and I'd prefer to keep it that way. :) I wouldn't mind subclassing `UITableViewCell` if that's a solution. Of course, I would like to implement this the "proper" way - only create a cell when one is needed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to make your cell in a xib file if you want to use the same cell type for both the main table and the search results table. You can make a subclass if you want (you only need to put in IBOutlets to your two labels in the .h file), or do it the same way you already did using tags. In viewDidLoad of the table view controller, register the nib for both tables,

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommonCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommonCell"];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommonCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommonCell"];
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you only need to dequeue the cell with that same identifier, and populate the labels. There's no need to check for cell equals nil, because it never will be.

I modified one of my apps to show how you can implement cellForRowAtIndexPath. I subclassed the cell (CommonCell is the class), only adding IBOutlets to the leftLabel, and rightLabel,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CommonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.leftLabel.text = ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView])? self.theData[indexPath.row] : self.filteredData[indexPath.row];
    cell.rightLabel.text = ([tableView isEqual:self.tableView])? self.theData[indexPath.row] : self.filteredData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've never used xib files before - only Storyboards and code and I'd prefer to keep it that way. :) I wouldn't mind subclassing if that's a solution.

Comment: @Joey, you really shouldn't use a cell you made in the storyboard main table view for the search results table -- I tried that once, and it gave me problems. This, and a few other cases are the only times I use a xib, otherwise I prefer storyboards. If you don't want to learn to make xibs, then you'll have to do it in code.

Comment: I would like my search results table cells to appear exactly the same as they do in the regular table. It was working perfect before I decided to tweak the default style. ;)

Comment: @Joey, that's why I suggested using a xib -- it's the best way to reuse a cell that you've spent time setting up how you want it. If you subclass your cell, it's extremely easy to do -- just check the box to use a xib when you create your cell subclass, and you'll have a xib file with a cell in it ready to modify (you can even delete that one and copy and paste the one you already made in the storyboard into the xib file).

Comment: You mentioned xib is the best way, what's the other options? :) I did subclass it (see Matteo's code). I looked into creating a xib and it made me choose between iPhone or iPad. This app is Universal so I must create both? If this is the best option I'll take it, can you provide more detailed info on how to get that set up.

Comment: @Joey, I updated my answer to show how to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath with a subclassed cell. You still do the nib registration as I originally posted. I think you do need 2 xibs, so you get the right sized cell for the different platforms.

Comment: @Joey, Actually, I just tested on the iPad, and my single xib made for iPhone worked fine.

Comment: @rdelmar: Storybord is a very bad thing. You looks like a GURU with your reputation (41k at the moment)..you shouldn't encourage developer to use Storyboard and i think you also know why.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi, I totally disagree with that sentiment. I see nothing wrong with using storyboards.  Why do you think they're so bad?

Comment: 1. You can't export part of your code like an object;
2. When you import an extern object obviously you import code or code+nib, so you will have a mix between storyboard, nib, code in your project.

In every good company is ALL WRITTEN by code or max with some NIB..never with Storyboard that also have a lot of problem. Storyboards were created to be the life of junior developer easier. Also Apple's developer say to not use Storyboard. You have a lot of reputation point..how is possible that you use Storyboard?

Comment: ***Reusability***

When it comes to moving or copying, Storyboards are poorly positioned. A Storyboard must be moved along with all of its dependent view controllers. In other words, a single view controller cannot be individually extracted and reused elsewhere as a single independent entity; it’s dependent on the rest of the Storyboard to function.

Comment: ***Data flow***

Data often needs to be passed between view controllers when an app transitions. However, the Storyboard’s visual flow is broken in this case as there’s no trace of this happening in the Interface Builder. Storyboards take care of handling the flow between view controllers, but not the flow of data. So, the destination controller has to be configured with code, overriding the visual experience.

Comment: @Joey, It works for me. If I select a cell in the storyboard, and do command-c, then go to the xib, click in the canvas (or the scene list) and do command-v, it pastes it in complete with its constraints.

Comment: Sorry, thanks, I got it to work. Didn't see your comment til after I deleted mine. Now that I have the cell in the xib, what do I need to do with the cell I created in storyboard? Delete everything in it?

Comment: @Joey, just delete the whole cell -- you want a "bare" table view with no cell inside, if you're going to be getting the cell from a xib.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was able to get that working beautifully again, even better than before. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is conceptually wrong: **you are instantiate a NEW CELL from code that is not the cell from interface builder**. If you want use that on interface builder you need to register the nib for your tableView, and associate it to an identifier (se the same identifier also in the cell on interface builder):

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NameNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
```

But the question is: why? The best thing to do is create a subclass and add your labels. It is really simple:

1) Create a new file **CustomSearchCell**  object that extends `UITableViewCell`:

**CustomSearchCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSearchCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *leftLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *rightLabel;

@end
```

**CustomSearchCell.m**

```
#import "CustomSearchCell.h"

@implementation CustomSearchCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _leftLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 45)];
        [_leftLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];
        [_leftLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        _rightLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 45, 200, 25)];
        [_rightLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]];
        [_rightLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        [self.contentView addSubview: _leftLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview: _rightLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

2) In your view controller:

```
#import "CustomSearchCell.h"
```

and:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCellIdentifier";
    CustomSearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomSearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.leftLabel = ...;
        cell.rightLabel = ...;
    }
    else {
        cell.leftLabel = ...;
        cell.rightLabel = ...;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: :) Same comment for you: I've never used xib files before - only Storyboards and code and I'd prefer to keep it that way. :) I wouldn't mind subclassing if that's a solution. Could you expand on that approach? I would like to do it the "proper" way - only create a cell when one is needed.

Comment: Surely i edit my reply. In any case: XIB --> storyboard ... Nib --> file no storyboard

Comment: Thank you, it's working I have just one problem. That initWithStyle method manually lays out the labels so it doesn't look the same as the main table. I already did that work (lots of it) in the Interface Builder with Auto Layout. How can I just reuse that cell layout I've already set up in IB? The search and main table should be identical in design.

Comment: You can simply set the position of the label..in CGRectMake(x, y, width, height). Take the same value from your IB

Comment: It's not just position, but also font size and color. Knowing me, I'd change something in the storyboard then forget I also need to change it in the code for the search table.

Comment: you can change the font, the color, etc by the code in cellForRow..:

[cell.leftLabel setFont:...]; so you can have difference from searchCell or not